# JavaScript - add and remove div onclick child href

Tags: javascript, html

In my form I have a href called `Add Record` which when clicked adds a new line of html elements to the form.  The added line of html elements has a `remove` and `add` href.  Upon clicking the `remove` at the end of the line, that specific line gets removed...however, when I click on the `add` on the child element, a new line is not getting created.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var html = '<div><label>Category:</label><select id="childcategory"><option value="0" selected>Select Category</option><option value="CatA">Category A</option><option value="CatB">Category B</option></select><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a><a href="#" id="childAdd">AddRecord</a></div>';
  var maxRows = 20;
  var x = 1;
  //Add rows
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#container").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  })

  /*//Add rows
  $("#container").on('click', '#childAdd', function(e){
      $(this).parent('div').add();
      x++;
      })
  })*/

  //Remove rows
  $("#container").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="block">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select id="category" name="category[]" required>
                          <option value="0" selected>Select Category</option>   
                          <option value="ToiletSoap">Toilet Soap</option>
                          <option value="ToothPaste">ToothPaste</option>
                        </select>
            <a href="#" id="add">Add record</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use same function to `add record`, I hope this is your expected out put, if not please comment, i will update

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var html = '<div><label>Category:</label><select id="childcategory"><option value="0" selected>Select Category</option><option value="CatA">Category A</option><option value="CatB">Category B</option></select><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a><a href="#" id="childAdd">AddRecord</a></div>';
  var maxRows = 20;
  var x = 1;
  //Add rows
  $("form").on('click','#add, #childAdd', function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#container").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  })


  //Remove rows
  $("#container").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="block">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select id="category" name="category[]" required>
                          <option value="0" selected>Select Category</option>   
                          <option value="ToiletSoap">Toilet Soap</option>
                          <option value="ToothPaste">ToothPaste</option>
                        </select>
            <a href="#" id="add">Add record</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you...never thought this could be so simple....and referring two element id's on a click is a new learning for me.

Comment: since we are adding dynamic element, we need to use `.on('method', 'selector', function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

In the code above

```
var html = '<div><label>Category:</label><select id="childcategory"><option value="0" selected>Select Category</option><option value="CatA">Category A</option><option value="CatB">Category B</option></select><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a><a href="#" id="childAdd">AddRecord</a></div>';

var maxRows = 20;
var x = 1;
//Add rows
$("#add").click(function(e) {       //<---  Try using #childAdd  instead of #add or change childAdd ID of href to add.
  if (x <= maxRows) {
    $("#container").append(html);
    x++;
  }
})
```

Because in HTML `add` href, you have used id as `childAdd`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you...however, identifying the child element with a different id is required otherwise it will conflict with the id `add` already used in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this be a different DIV?

```
$("#container").append(html);
```

> > > >
> > >       $("#main-content").append(html);

Comment: Thank you ...I tried using a separate id for the child element inside 'var html' but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not prefer giving the same id, use classes instead of ids
2. You missed `append(html)` while adding rows

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var html = '<div><label>Category:</label><select id="childcategory"><option value="0" selected>Select Category</option><option value="CatA">Category A</option><option value="CatB">Category B</option></select><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a><a href="#" class="childAdd">AddRecord</a></div>';
  var maxRows = 20;
  var x = 1;
  //Add rows
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#container").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  })

  //Add rows
  $("#container").on('click', '.childAdd', function(e){
      $(this).parent('div').append(html);
      console.log("child add")
      x++;
      })
 

  //Remove rows
  $("#container").on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="block">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select id="category" name="category[]" required>
                          <option value="0" selected>Select Category</option>   
                          <option value="ToiletSoap">Toilet Soap</option>
                          <option value="ToothPaste">ToothPaste</option>
                        </select>
            <a href="#" id="add">Add record</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you...this also works....I tried this but with an id and not as a class for childAdd....and with id it rendered even the first add record button dysfunctional.